# How to left join 2 dataframes in python,if more than one matching row in 2nd data frame after filter, join with the first row

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 dataframes, each having a column with datatime as datatype.
I want to join second dataframe with first with the following conditions

1. find the rows of first dataframe whose datetime value between datetime value of second dataframe and 10 minutes before
2. if more than one such rows, then take the first one
3. if no such row, then fill with empty or null
4. One row can be joined only once.

Now I am doing in the following way. I would like to know, if there are any better ways to reduce the total running time.

```
from datetime import datetime
import datetime as dt
import pandas as pd


df1 = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['Enter_Time', 'Unique_Id'])
df1.loc[len(df1)] = [datetime.strptime('2018-10-01 06:29:00','%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'), 'A']
df1.loc[len(df1)] = [datetime.strptime('2018-10-01 06:30:00','%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'), 'B']
df1.loc[len(df1)] = [datetime.strptime('2018-10-01 06:31:00','%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'), 'C']
df1.loc[len(df1)] = [datetime.strptime('2018-10-01 06:32:00','%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'), 'D']
df1.loc[len(df1)] = [datetime.strptime('2018-10-01 06:33:00','%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'), 'E']
df1.loc[len(df1)] = [datetime.strptime('2018-10-01 08:29:00','%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'), 'F']
df1.loc[len(df1)] = [datetime.strptime('2018-10-01 08:30:00','%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'), 'G']
df1.loc[len(df1)] = [datetime.strptime('2018-10-01 08:31:00','%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'), 'H']
df1.loc[len(df1)] = [datetime.strptime('2018-10-01 08:32:00','%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'), 'I']
df1.loc[len(df1)] = [datetime.strptime('2018-10-01 08:33:00','%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'), 'j']


df2 = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['Transaction_Time', 'Amount'])
df2.loc[len(df2)] = [datetime.strptime('2018-10-01 06:40:00','%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'), 10.25]
df2.loc[len(df2)] = [datetime.strptime('2018-10-01 07:40:00','%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'), 3.96]
df2.loc[len(df2)] = [datetime.strptime('2018-10-01 08:31:00','%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'), 9.65]
df2.loc[len(df2)] = [datetime.strptime('2018-10-01 08:32:00','%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'), 2.84]

df3 = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['Transaction_Time', 'Amount', 'Enter_Time', 'Unique_Id'])

for id, row in df2.iterrows():
    Transaction_Time = row['Transaction_Time']
    Transaction_Time_Before = Transaction_Time - dt.timedelta(seconds = 600)
    Result_Row = {
        'Transaction_Time' : row['Transaction_Time'],
        'Amount' : row['Amount'],
        'Enter_Time' : '',
        'Unique_Id' : ''
    }

    dfFiletered = df1[(df1["Enter_Time"] < Transaction_Time) & (df1["Enter_Time"] >= Transaction_Time_Before)].sort_values(by= ['Enter_Time'],ascending=True)
    if len(dfFiletered) > 0:
        firstRow = dfFiletered.iloc[0]
        Result_Row['Enter_Time'] = firstRow['Enter_Time']
        Result_Row['Unique_Id'] = firstRow['Unique_Id']
        df1.drop(df1[df1["Unique_Id"] == firstRow['Unique_Id']].index, inplace=True)
    df3.loc[len(df3)] = Result_Row
print(df3)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [merge_asof()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge_asof.html):

```
pd.merge_asof(df1,
              df2,
              left_on='Enter_Time',
              right_on='Transaction_Time',
              tolerance=pd.Timedelta('10m'),
              direction='forward')
```

And it would produce:

```
#           Enter_Time Unique_Id    Transaction_Time  Amount
#0 2018-10-01 06:29:00         A                 NaT     NaN
#1 2018-10-01 06:30:00         B 2018-10-01 06:40:00   10.25
#2 2018-10-01 06:31:00         C 2018-10-01 06:40:00   10.25
#3 2018-10-01 06:32:00         D 2018-10-01 06:40:00   10.25
#4 2018-10-01 06:33:00         E 2018-10-01 06:40:00   10.25
#5 2018-10-01 08:29:00         F 2018-10-01 08:31:00    9.65
#6 2018-10-01 08:30:00         G 2018-10-01 08:31:00    9.65
#7 2018-10-01 08:31:00         H 2018-10-01 08:31:00    9.65
#8 2018-10-01 08:32:00         I 2018-10-01 08:32:00    2.84
#9 2018-10-01 08:33:00         j                 NaT     NaN
```

And to keep only first use:

```
df = pd.merge_asof(df1,
                   df2,
                   left_on='Enter_Time',
                   right_on='Transaction_Time',
                   tolerance=pd.Timedelta('10m'),
                   direction='forward')

df.loc[df.duplicated(['Transaction_Time', 'Amount']), ['Transaction_Time', 'Amount']] = (np.nan, np.nan)
df
#           Enter_Time Unique_Id    Transaction_Time  Amount
#0 2018-10-01 06:29:00         A                 NaT     NaN
#1 2018-10-01 06:30:00         B 2018-10-01 06:40:00   10.25
#2 2018-10-01 06:31:00         C                 NaT     NaN
#3 2018-10-01 06:32:00         D                 NaT     NaN
#4 2018-10-01 06:33:00         E                 NaT     NaN
#5 2018-10-01 08:29:00         F 2018-10-01 08:31:00    9.65
#6 2018-10-01 08:30:00         G                 NaT     NaN
#7 2018-10-01 08:31:00         H                 NaT     NaN
#8 2018-10-01 08:32:00         I 2018-10-01 08:32:00    2.84
#9 2018-10-01 08:33:00         j                 NaT     NaN
```

**EDIT**

To merge `df2` with `df1` I guess you need to leave default direction (`'backward'`):

```
df = pd.merge_asof(df2,
                   df1,
                   left_on='Transaction_Time',
                   right_on='Enter_Time',
                   tolerance=pd.Timedelta('10m'))

df.loc[df.duplicated(['Transaction_Time', 'Amount']), ['Transaction_Time', 'Amount']] = (np.nan, np.nan)
#     Transaction_Time  Amount          Enter_Time Unique_Id
#0 2018-10-01 06:40:00   10.25 2018-10-01 06:33:00         E
#1 2018-10-01 07:40:00    3.96                 NaT       NaN
#2 2018-10-01 08:31:00    9.65 2018-10-01 08:31:00         H
#3 2018-10-01 08:32:00    2.84 2018-10-01 08:32:00         I
```

The transformation of duplicated doesn't affect your example, but it is there to solve issue in question.

Comment: I tried it `df4 = pd.merge_asof(df2,
              df1,
              left_on='Transaction_Time',
              right_on='Enter_Time',
              tolerance=pd.Timedelta('10m'),
              direction='forward')`
but the first row doesn't get any maches. How to get the correct join for first row also ?

Comment: Sorry, If my question caused  confusion. df2 is the left dataframe, to which I would like to join df1. So your example would be as follows `df = pd.merge_asof(df2,
                   df1,
                   left_on='Transaction_Time',
                   right_on='Enter_Time',
                   tolerance=pd.Timedelta('10m'),
                   direction='forward')`. It works but 2nd rows from the df1 is joined, not the first one. Also first row doesn't get any join. I tried with '11m' as delta value, but the same resutl

Comment: @Xpeditions I think the direction should be default, like in edit.

Comment: Transaction time 6:40 joins with enter time 6:33.But it should join with enter time 6:30 - first one from 10 minutes interval.